# Using RoleModel gem: How to remove all the previously assigned roles from a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan, role

In my RoR application, I use Role Model and CanCan gems. There is no default role for users. 
Before I assign roles to a user, role_mask is empty. I can assign multiple roles. But I cannot remove all the roles and make roles_mask to nil again. The last role assigned will still exists
I need to remove previously assigned roles, ALL of them!! is it possible??

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make a single user roles to nil then in your role modify action do like

```
 user.roles_mask = nil
```

and save

if you want to make all the roles mask nil then you can do this by writing a rake task.
something like

```
task :make_roles_nil => :environment do
User.all.each do |user|
user.roles_mask = nil
user.save
end
end
```

Put it into lib/tasks directory a file named user.rake
and then run

```
bundle exec rake user:make_roles_nil RAILS_ENV = YOUR ENVIRONMENT(development or production)
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I wanted to do it on individual user, on the front end. At the console I can just select a user and make roles_mask = nil. On the front end, when i check a checkbox that role gets assigned but when I uncheck the roles_mask value is not nil....

Comment: ok in the role model gem there is no default option to do so.You can check it manually if the roles checkboxes are not any selected then make roles_mask = nil Or you can add a flag and add a checkbox with the roles checkbox, saying that 'empty all roles' and check it into your controller.If th flag is set then make roles_mask nil.Thats it

Comment: You could make that rake task faster by performing the update directly in SQL rather than loading each record into memory: _User.update_all("roles_mask = null")_